# Should I be able to modify this final property? Books says I should but I'm getting an error

Tags: groovy

Groovy noob here, I'm working through my first Groovy book and it has example code where it states roughly

**"If I want a property to be a ready-only property then declare it final.  This is not defining a `final` field but a read-only property-you can change the property from within instance methods of the defining class, but not from outside"**

Here is the code I have in question, but I keep getting an error stating:

`cannot modify final field 'miles' outside of constructor.`

Code:

```
class Car
{
    final miles = 0

    def getMiles()
    {
        println "getMiles called"
        miles
    }

    def drive(dist){if (dist>0) miles += dist }

}
```

The book says I should be able to modify `miles` from within the `drive` instance method, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I am working through the same book and wrote the same code and was given this issue, thanks for posting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what they meant (not sure what they said, if you're paraphrasing) is that there's no setter method defined, so it can't be modified from outside the class.

It *is*, however, still a `final` property, which means it can't be modified once its set, which would be in a constructor or during the declaration.

[Property and field rules](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Beans#GroovyBeans-Propertyandfieldrules)

That said, see these two issues: [1628](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-1628), [2752](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-2752), so more exploration might be necessary, although this appears limited to local script properties.

My guess is you're using a 1.7+ Groovy, while the book targets <= 1.6.

See also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930735/groovy-1-7-changes-final).

Comment: can I declare something like: `def final miles`?

Comment: That question you reference speaks about same book and chapter I am on.  Looks like the book was written for <1.6 and Im using 1.8 to play with.

Comment: @ProfessionalAmateur Yep; they fixed it (although it took a year or two!)